# Loop through two querysets while highlighting differences in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

I have a model class defined as below:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    stock_number = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    vin = models.CharField(max_length=17)
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    manufacturer_popularity = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    series = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, null=True)
    exterior_colour = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    interior_colour = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    interior_type = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    doors = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    passengers = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    body_style = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    transmission = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fuel_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    engine_capacity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    cylinders = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    drive_train = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

What I want to do is to query two databases based on the above class then display the data in a template while showing the differences between each paired Vehicle entry in red.  The querying bit isn't the main issue I guess since I'll need something like:

```
set1 = Vehicle.objects.all()
set2 = Vehicle.objects.using('other_db').all()
```

But how can I have the pairing and display being handled?  I hope someone can show me the light here.

**UPDATE 1**

```
vehicles = []
for v1 in set1:
    for v2 in set2:
        if v1['stock_number'] == v2['stock_number']:
            vehicle1 = vehicle2 = {}
            vehicle1['vehicle_1'] = v1
            vehicle2['vehicle_2'] = v2
            vehicles.append(vehicle1)
            vehicles.append(vehicle2)
        else:
            vehicle1 = vehicle2 = {}
            vehicle1['vehicle_1'] = v1
            vehicle2['vehicle_2'] = {}
            vehicles.append(vehicle1)
            vehicles.append(vehicle2)
```

Comment: Do you know whether you'll have a 1-to-1 ratio between the DB's? Is there some key you can use to make sure you're talking about the same vehicle both times?

Comment: Part of why I need the view is to ensure the 1-to-1 ratio, but yes, there is a sort of key I guess...the stock numbers should match between the DB's, and that's what uniquely identifies each record...if not then that pair will have only one item for whichever DB has the record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea

```
from itertools import izip

for obj1, obj2 in izip(set1, set2):
    for field in obj1._meta.fields:
        if field.value_from_object(obj1) == field.value_from_object(obj2):
            print 'Same value', field.value_from_object(obj1)
        else:
            print 'Obj1 has', field.value_from_object(obj1)
            print 'Obj2 has', field.value_from_object(obj2)
```

Comment: Based on your idea above, I tried building a nested dictionary from the two querysets, but it seems the process is too CPU intensive and takes forever to complete.  Is my idea on track based on your above sample?  Please take a look at the code I've added...that's what I'm using.  Currently there are about 670 records per queryset

Comment: @Stephen M And what's wrong with my code? Have you try to adapt it? My code will make 670 iterations and yours — 670 * 670 iterations. And what do you want to get as the result? Can you show an example: here's set1, here's set2, here's what I want to get?

Comment: My bad for not replying for ages...your code worked well.  Thnx